# Issue with IK armature messing up when I try to shrink my model

Tags: armature, scale, inverse-kinematics

Hi there I'm starting out and just finished making my first model that has a IK to FK switch, but I only realized afterwords it was way bigger than I'd have liked, so I went to scale it and this happened [image] So I tried a few things like changing the transform orientation and pivot points but had no luck and then I noticed the issue seemed to be with certain IK bones, so I switched from IK to FK and tried scaling it again and got this [image]So it seems like the issue is with certain IK bones messing up but I don't have a clue why that'd be, they don't look to have any differences with other IK bones. Any ideas? I can provide more info if needed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Had to change some of the IK bones from World space to Local space, that fixed the scaling issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to object mode <kbd>TAB</kbd>, select your armature, and press <kbd>CTRL + A</kbd> to apply scale if you didn't do it before.

Hope that solves your problem :)

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of how to apply scale, but that's not the issue, the issue is the IK rigged bones in the armature go all weird when I try to scale it down.